# Oracle performance loss from 10.1.0.2 to 10.2.0.5

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-10g

I am testing an application on two database servers with the same data :

- **10.1.0.2** on Windows (for development)
- **10.2.0.5** on Solaris (for validation).

We have a script which recreates a huge table (> 100 millions of rows) and its index. The performance for doing this is OK on both platforms and we get almost the same times (about 1 hour).

The structure is created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "PART" 
(
    "PARTNUMBER" VARCHAR2(9 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SUBPARTNUMBER" VARCHAR2(12 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ISSUE" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "PROG" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TYPE_NAME" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    "FROM" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TO" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
);

CREATE INDEX "PART_INDEX" ON "PART" ("PARTNUMBER", "TO", "FROM", "TYPE_NAME") COMPRESS;
```

Then we gather statistics on the table (and implicitly on the index):

```
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(null,'PART');
```

There is a performance issue on a query which takes less than 5 second on the 10.1.0.2 but more than 5 minutes on the 10.2.0.5:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    p.SUBPARTNUMBER,
    p.PROG,
    p.TYPE,
    p.TYPE_NAME
FROM PART p, VW_VEHICLES v
WHERE p.PARTNUMBER= 'A12345678'
    AND p.PROG      =   v.PROG
    AND p.TYPE      =   'V'
    AND v.TYPE_NAME =   p.TYPE_NAME
    AND v.RANK BETWEEN p.FROM AND p.TO
ORDER BY p.PARTNUMBER;
```

I looked at the statistics tab in SQLDeveloper on both platform, it is similar for the TABLE, but for the index there is a big difference on the key `DISTINCT_KEYS`:

```
 -  10.1.0.2 : DISTINCT_KEYS = 144800
 -  10.2.0.5 : DISTINCT_KEYS = 44404445
```

**Do you know what can explain these differences ?**

The second server (Solaris) should be more powerful and more efficient than the Windows one which is a workstation with less memory and inefficient HDD.

Here are the explain plans for both platforms:

- 10.1.0.2

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Id  | Operation                      | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Inst   |IN-OUT|
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                          |    11 |   759 |  8291   (1)| 00:01:40 |        |      |
> |   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                 |                          |    11 |   759 |  8291   (1)| 00:01:40 |        |      |
> |   2 |   SORT UNIQUE                  |                          |    11 |   759 |  8290   (1)| 00:01:40 |        |      |
> |*  3 |    HASH JOIN                   |                          |    11 |   759 |  8289   (1)| 00:01:40 |        |      |
> |   4 |     VIEW                       |                          |  2795 | 81055 |   114 (-12)| 00:00:02 |        |      |
> |   5 |      UNION-ALL                 |                          |       |       |            |          |        |      |
> |   6 |       REMOTE                   |                          |     1 |    32 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | VEHIC~ | R->S |
> |   7 |       REMOTE                   |                          |  7790 |   281K|    14   (0)| 00:00:01 | VEHIC~ | R->S |
> |*  8 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PART                     |  6579 |   256K|  8159   (1)| 00:01:38 |        |      |
> |*  9 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | PART_INDEX               |     1 |       |    41   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

- 10.2.0.5

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Id  | Operation                     | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Inst   |IN-OUT|
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                          |     1 |    69 |   302   (1)| 00:00:05 |        |      |
> |   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                |                          |     1 |    69 |   302   (1)| 00:00:05 |        |      |
> |   2 |   SORT UNIQUE                 |                          |     1 |    69 |   301   (1)| 00:00:05 |        |      |
> |*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PART                     |     1 |    40 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
> |   4 |     NESTED LOOPS              |                          |     1 |    69 |   300   (0)| 00:00:05 |        |      |
> |   5 |      VIEW                     |                          |   100 |  2900 |     5 (100)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
> |   6 |       UNION-ALL               |                          |       |       |            |          |        |      |
> |   7 |        REMOTE                 |                          |       |       |            |          | VEHIC~ | R->S |
> |   8 |        REMOTE                 |                          |       |       |            |          | VEHIC~ | R->S |
> |*  9 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN         | PART_INDEX               |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

I am also trying to investigate on a 11g...

Comment: It is worth pointing out that overall RISC chips tend to preform worse than CISC chips based on the fact that operations in a RISC environment take more clock cycles than operations in a CISC environment. That was a tradeoff that was made back when clock speeds were faster on RISC chips. If your Solaris machine uses a Sparc chip, than it will likely be slower that an Intel server. Bearing in mind that there are other factors that effect performance besides the type of CPU. You also have different explain plans. You may want to compare SGA and optimizer between the environments.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> Then we gather statistics on the table (and implicitly on the index):

but statistics on indexes aren't gathered unless you do this:

```
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(null,'PART',cascade=>true);
```

What appears to be happening is index statistics are not being gathered (or not gathered correctly) on 10.2.0.5; if specifying `cascade=>true` doesn't help, you may want to consider gathering the index statistics separately via `dbms_stats.gather_index_stats(null, 'PART_INDEX', estimate_percent=>20)`.  You might also need to set a higher value for estimate_percent.

You may also want to ensure you have set system statistics (which tell the optimizer how fast your disks are, how much CPU you have, etc.) via the `dbms_stats.gather_system_stats`  and `dbms_stats.set_system_stats` procedures.  I think that 10.2 is more sensitive to system statistics.